# Proving continuity of potentials and fields due to a surface charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

Is there a way to show:

$(1)\ \displaystyle \phi=\int_{S'} \dfrac{\sigma}{r} dS'$ is continuous all over space

$(2)\ \mathbf{E}=\displaystyle\int_{S'} \dfrac{\sigma}{r^2}\ \hat{\mathbf{r}}\ dS'$ is continuous everywhere except at boundary $S'$

where $\sigma$ is the surface charge density

Comment: Why is this site so inactive? I am only getting question likes but no answers.